# Missing Windows 7 when i installed ubuntu 12.4

Tags: installation, grub2, bootloader, re-installation

i am newbie to this i installed Ubuntu using separate drive and i choose windows 7 loader as a boot device loader and after the installation i can only choose Ubuntu no windows 7 os so please help me to solve this .

Comment: keeep pressing left shift when you start your pc... maybe this might help.

Answer (score 3):

Boot using a live usb/cd of ubuntu. 
Use `boot-repair` to fix the problem.

After booting with live usb/cd ,Run following command in terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Use `Recomended Repair`

At the end this will give you url , post it here if unresolved.

Also in live mode see the windows file are there or not.

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look at this article on how to add windows 7 manually to the Ubuntu Grub2 menu](http://technologytales.com/2010/11/21/manually-adding-an-entry-for-windows-7-to-an-ubuntu-grub2-menu/)

Comment: (hi thnx for the helping i did but i have no idea about the correct root .(hd0,msdos2) is not the correct root then i changed to(hd1,msdos2) bt upgrading grub2 they displaying cannot read from '/dev /sdb ) how to get the correct root for windows 7 please help

Comment: you need to change to the correct root on your machine. example (hd1,msdos2) may not be the case with you.  Best is to open disk utility, and find out the right drive in you specific case.

Comment: Thank you for helping me i did but at boot time its showing "windows7 loader " but when i am clicking on it nothing happening ( cursor is blinking),then i need to reboot .is it any other way to get windows 7